# Unable to Resolve Parameter Resolution in Shared Library Module ([object Object], ?, ?) - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am trying to import a custom shared component library into an Angular application that I have upgraded from Angular 5 from Angular 4.

However, I am having a problem that I am unable to resolve.

The error is as follows:

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LibSharedComponentsModule: ([object Object], ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15692)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15527)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15326)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:15125)
    at eval (compiler.js:15223)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15201)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34385)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34346)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:485
CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:15692
CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:15527
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:15326
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary @ compiler.js:15125
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:15223
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:15201
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:34385
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:34346
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:34240
CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:239
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5551
(anonymous) @ main.ts:11
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:174
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
0 @ main.bundle.js:189
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

`LibSharedComponentsModule` is my library and I do not understand what the parameters error is referring to.

I have pasted my `AppModule` and `LibSharedComponentsModule` code below:

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// Auth0 library for authentication
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

// Apollo for GraphQL queries
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloLink, from } from 'apollo-link';

// PrimeNG components
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CarouselModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ChipsModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CodeHighlighterModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ContextMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataGridModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataScrollerModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DragDropModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FieldsetModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GalleriaModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GMapModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GrowlModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputMaskModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputSwitchModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputTextareaModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { LightboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ListboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MegaMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { OrderListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { OverlayPanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PaginatorModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PanelMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PickListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ProgressBarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { RadioButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { RatingModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ScheduleModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SelectButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SlideMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SliderModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SpinnerModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SplitButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { StepsModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TabMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TerminalModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TieredMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ToggleButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ToolbarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TreeModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TreeTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

// Admin components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppMenuComponent, AppSubMenuComponent } from './app.menu.component';
import { AppSideBarComponent } from './app.sidebar.component';
import {AppSidebartabcontentComponent} from './app.sidebartabcontent.component';
import {AppTopbarComponent} from './app.topbar.component';
import {AppFooterComponent} from './app.footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './admin/dashboard.component';
import { StudentDetailsComponent } from './admin/studentdetails.component';
import { RequestsComponent } from './admin/requests.component';
import { EmptyDemo } from './admin/emptydemo';
import { CallbackComponent } from './admin/callback.component';

import { LibSharedComponentsModule } from 'lib-shared-components';

import { ToasterService } from 'lib-shared-components';
import { StudentService } from 'lib-shared-components';
import { AuthService } from 'lib-shared-components';
import { ErrorService } from 'lib-shared-components';
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from 'lib-shared-components';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ApiModule.forConfig(apiConfig),
        // ApolloModule.forRoot(provideClient),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutes,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AccordionModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        BreadcrumbModule,
        ButtonModule,
        CalendarModule,
        CarouselModule,
        ChartModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        ChipsModule,
        CodeHighlighterModule,
        ConfirmDialogModule,
        SharedModule,
        ContextMenuModule,
        DataGridModule,
        DataListModule,
        DataScrollerModule,
        DataTableModule,
        DialogModule,
        DragDropModule,
        DropdownModule,
        EditorModule,
        FieldsetModule,
        FileUploadModule,
        GalleriaModule,
        GMapModule,
        GrowlModule,
        InputMaskModule,
        InputSwitchModule,
        InputTextModule,
        InputTextareaModule,
        LightboxModule,
        ListboxModule,
        MegaMenuModule,
        MenuModule,
        MenubarModule,
        MessagesModule,
        MultiSelectModule,
        OrderListModule,
        OverlayPanelModule,
        PaginatorModule,
        PanelModule,
        PanelMenuModule,
        PasswordModule,
        PickListModule,
        ProgressBarModule,
        RadioButtonModule,
        RatingModule,
        ScheduleModule,
        SelectButtonModule,
        SlideMenuModule,
        SliderModule,
        SpinnerModule,
        SplitButtonModule,
        StepsModule,
        TabMenuModule,
        TabViewModule,
        TerminalModule,
        TieredMenuModule,
        ToggleButtonModule,
        ToolbarModule,
        TooltipModule,
        TreeModule,
        TreeTableModule,
        LibSharedComponentsModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppMenuComponent,
        AppSubMenuComponent,
        AppSideBarComponent,
        AppTopbarComponent,
        AppFooterComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        StudentDetailsComponent,
        RequestsComponent,
        EmptyDemo,
        CallbackComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        AuthService, AuthenticatedGuard, ToasterService, StudentService, { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    constructor(
        apollo: Apollo,
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
        httpLink, HttpLink
      ) {
        const http = httpLink.create({uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'});

        const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
            // add the authorization to the headers
            // we assume `headers` as a defined instance of HttpHeaders
            operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
              headers: headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null),
            }));

            return forward(operation);
          });

        //   const otherMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
        //     // add the authorization to the headers
        //     // we assume `headers` as a defined instance of HttpHeaders
        //     operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
        //       headers: headers.append('recent-activity', localStorage.getItem('lastOnlineTime') || null)
        //     }));

        //     return forward(operation);
        //   });

        //   otherMiddleware,

          apollo.create({
            link: from([authMiddleware, http]),
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
            connectToDevTools: true,
          });
        }
    }
```

**LibSharedComponentsModule**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// PrimeNG for UI Components
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { BreadcrumbModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CarouselModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ChipsModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CodeHighlighterModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ContextMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataGridModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataScrollerModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DragDropModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FieldsetModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GalleriaModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GMapModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GrowlModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputMaskModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputSwitchModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { InputTextareaModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { LightboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ListboxModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MegaMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { OrderListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { OverlayPanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PaginatorModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PanelMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { PickListModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ProgressBarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { RadioButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { RatingModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ScheduleModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SelectButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SlideMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SliderModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SpinnerModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SplitButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { StepsModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TabMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TerminalModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TieredMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ToggleButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ToolbarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TreeModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TreeTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

// Auth0 library for authentication
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

// Apollo for GraphQL queries
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloLink, from } from 'apollo-link';

// Component Import 
import { DeleteButtonComponent } from './component/deletebutton.component';
import { StudentRequestComponent } from './component/studentrequest.component';
import { StudentPersonalDetailsComponent } from './component/studentpersonaldetails.component';
import { StudentSearchComponent } from './component/studentsearch.component';
import { StudentLetterComponent } from './component/studentletter.component';
import { LetterDetailsComponent } from './component/letterdetails.component';
import { RequestDetailsComponent } from './component/requestdetails.component';
import { RequestProcessComponent } from './component/requestprocess.component';
import { ViewCommentComponent } from './component/viewcomment.component';
import { ViewProgramComponent } from './component/viewprogram.component';
import { ViewQuoteComponent } from './component/viewquote.component';

// Service Import
import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';
import { ToasterService } from './service/alert.service';
import { StudentService } from './service/student.service';
import { ErrorService } from './service/error.service';
import { AuthenticatedGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

// Component Export
export * from './component/deletebutton.component';
export * from './component/studentpersonaldetails.component';
export * from './component/studentsearch.component';
export * from './component/studentrequest.component';
export * from './component/studentletter.component';
export * from './component/letterdetails.component';
export * from './component/requestprocess.component';
export * from './component/requestdetails.component';
export * from './component/viewcomment.component';
export * from './component/viewprogram.component';
export * from './component/viewquote.component';

// Service Export
export * from './service/auth.service';
export * from './service/alert.service';
export * from './service/student.service';
export * from './service/error.service';

// Guard Export
export * from './guards/auth.guard'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    // BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AccordionModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    BreadcrumbModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CalendarModule,
    CarouselModule,
    ChartModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    ChipsModule,
    CodeHighlighterModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    SharedModule,
    ContextMenuModule,
    DataGridModule,
    DataListModule,
    DataScrollerModule,
    DataTableModule,
    DialogModule,
    DragDropModule,
    DropdownModule,
    EditorModule,
    FieldsetModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    GalleriaModule,
    GMapModule,
    GrowlModule,
    InputMaskModule,
    InputSwitchModule,
    InputTextModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    LightboxModule,
    ListboxModule,
    MegaMenuModule,
    MenuModule,
    MenubarModule,
    MessagesModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    OrderListModule,
    OverlayPanelModule,
    PaginatorModule,
    PanelModule,
    PanelMenuModule,
    PasswordModule,
    PickListModule,
    ProgressBarModule,
    RadioButtonModule,
    RatingModule,
    ScheduleModule,
    SelectButtonModule,
    SlideMenuModule,
    SliderModule,
    SpinnerModule,
    SplitButtonModule,
    StepsModule,
    TabMenuModule,
    TabViewModule,
    TerminalModule,
    TieredMenuModule,
    ToggleButtonModule,
    ToolbarModule,
    TooltipModule,
    TreeModule,
    TreeTableModule,
    // AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  declarations: [
    DeleteButtonComponent,
    StudentPersonalDetailsComponent,
    StudentSearchComponent,
    StudentLetterComponent,
    StudentRequestComponent,
    LetterDetailsComponent,
    RequestProcessComponent,
    RequestDetailsComponent,
    ViewCommentComponent,
    ViewProgramComponent,
    ViewQuoteComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    DeleteButtonComponent,
    StudentPersonalDetailsComponent,
    StudentSearchComponent,
    StudentLetterComponent,
    StudentRequestComponent,
    LetterDetailsComponent,
    RequestProcessComponent,
    RequestDetailsComponent,
    ViewCommentComponent,
    ViewProgramComponent,
    ViewQuoteComponent
  ]
})
export class LibSharedComponentsModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibSharedComponentsModule,
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthenticatedGuard,
        ToasterService,
        StudentService,
        ErrorService,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorService }]
    };
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
  constructor(
    apollo: Apollo,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    httpLink, HttpLink
  ) {
    const http = httpLink.create({uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'});

    const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
        // add the authorization to the headers
        // we assume `headers` as a defined instance of HttpHeaders
        operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
          headers: headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null),
        }));

        return forward(operation);
      });

      // const otherMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
      //   // add the authorization to the headers
      //   // we assume `headers` as a defined instance of HttpHeaders
      //   operation.setContext(({ headers }) => ({
      //     headers: headers.append('recent-activity', localStorage.getItem('lastOnlineTime') || null)
      //   }));

      //   return forward(operation);
      // });

      // otherMiddleware

      apollo.create({
        link: from([authMiddleware, http]),
        cache: new InMemoryCache()
      });
    }
}
```

If anyone could advise how I could drill down further into this error using a debugger or advise how to resolve it, it would be very much appreciated. I am using `Webpack` if that makes any difference.

Comment: At least this `httpLink, HttpLink` should be changed to `httpLink: HttpLink`. This is a mistake, and I suppose that `tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable` was  added to stop TSLint complaining about it (a mistake, too). The answer already suggests that but in uncertain manner. If this still doesn't solve the problem, please, fix it and update the question with current error message.

Comment: Thank you. I made the adjustment as both answers suggested and I now get a different error as a result of a different problem but I can now work towards resolving that. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take closer look at this part:

```
constructor(
    apollo: Apollo,
    //  tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    httpLink, HttpLink // <-- are you sure about that comma? looks more like there should be a colon here
) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, that did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @Ben, You actually have it in both AppModule and 
LibSharedComponentsModule, please correct both and try. Also it's better to check if you have more of that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `inject`:

```
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular'; 
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
```

But it's like they are not registered in angular `DI`'s providers.
Import it to your `LibSharedComponentsModule` module:

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
> import { ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular';
> import { HttpLinkModule } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     HttpClientModule, // provides HttpClient for HttpLink
>     ApolloModule,
>     HttpLinkModule
>   ]
> })
> class LibSharedComponentsModule {}
> ```